# how to find the query used for creation of Temporary table in Oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I have created a temporary table in oracle sql developer but I forgot to save it and now I want to reuse the query but I don't remember the code used then. Is there a process to get query used creation of temp table?

Comment: is it global temp table or local??

Comment: @Biswabid: Oracle has no "local" temporary tables

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()`

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE')
from dual;
```

The result is a CLOB with the complete DDL. You might need to adjust the display in SQL Developer to make the content of that value fully visible (I don't use SQL Developer, so I don't know if that is necessary and if so, what you would need to do)

**Edit:**

It seems SQL Developer can't display the result of this query properly unless you use the "Run Script" option. And with that you need to use a `SET LONG 60000` (or some other big number) before you run it, to see the complete source code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply but it's showing the column description only it's not showing the query I have used.

Comment: @sravankumar: that **will** return the **complete** DDL for the definition of the table. Maybe SQL Developer doesn't show everything from the CLOB

Comment: From pl sql developer: select the table, right click, select "dbms metadata" and select ddl...

Comment: what options do you have?  it has something like DDL in it as far as I remember

Comment: @sandman: you don't need to "click" anywhere. Just run that statement.

Comment: I advised the click option because he said he had a problem running the DDL extract statement